# Ascii color prefixes in PureScript doesn't work

Tags: colors, ascii, purescript

I want to colorize my string with ASCII colors, but the following code...

```hs
data Color = White | Red | Green | Yellow

colorizeWith :: Color -> String -> String
colorizeWith Green  s = "\031[0;33m" <> s <> "\033[0m"
colorizeWith Red    s = "\032[0;33m" <> s <> "\033[0m"
colorizeWith Yellow s = "\033[0;33m" <> s <> "\033[0m"
colorizeWith White  s = "\097[0;33m" <> s <> "\033[0m"
```

...doesn't work. It shows this build error:

```
Error found:
at src/Main.purs:33:27 - 33:28 (line 33, column 27 - line 33, column 28)

  Unable to parse module:
  Illegal character escape code
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, in PureScript string literals escaped character codes start with `\x` and are required to be hexadecimal. So, for example:

```hs
"\x31\x32\x33" == "123"
```

But beyond that, you seem to have your escape sequences all mixed up.

**First**, the escape symbol, decimal `27`, hexadecimal `1B`, octal `33`, which is apparently what you're trying to do, but you put it in the wrong place - as color parameter instead of the escape sequence opening. You seem to have swapped the color codes with the opening escape symbols.

**Second**, you seem to have swapped red and green. Red is 31, green is 32.

So, taking into account all of the above, this is how your code should look:

```hs
colorizeWith :: Color -> String -> String
colorizeWith Green  s = "\x1B[0;32m" <> s <> "\x1B[0m"
colorizeWith Red    s = "\x1B[0;31m" <> s <> "\x1B[0m"
colorizeWith Yellow s = "\x1B[0;33m" <> s <> "\x1B[0m"
colorizeWith White  s = "\x1B[0;97m" <> s <> "\x1B[0m"
```